# Nested PageView causes shadows to clip. How to avoid the shadow from getting clipped?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, shadow, flutter-pageview

I have a simple nested PageView :

```
class PackViewVertical extends Stateless {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.63),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return PageView.builder(
                controller:
                    PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.63),
                itemCount: sampleCard.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, ind) {
                  return sampleCard[ind];
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}
List sampleCard = [
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.redAccent, offset: Offset(0, 10), blurRadius: 150.0),
      ],
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.blueGrey, offset: Offset(0, 10), blurRadius: 150.0),
      ],
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.yellow, offset: Offset(0, 10), blurRadius: 150.0),
      ],
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
  ),
];
```

and this is the result: [There is no boundary between the cards in horizontal view **inner PageView** But there is boundary in the **vertical PageView** which you can see it like a *line* when I add shadow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2RrK.jpg)

My question is: How can I remove that boundary (from vertical view as well) to have a uniform background ? somthing like this: [(I want the shadows to be uniform (like blended and reached to the next color) in the vertical view similar to horizontal view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rzOY.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your `Container` shadows are getting clipped by their `PageView` parents.

You can avoid shadow clipping with the help of `PageView.clipBehavior` property by setting it to `Clip.none`.

Add this to **both** of your `PageView`s,

```
clipBehavior: Clip.none
```

[image]